# Загружаются не все файлы из списка

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Работаю над обновлением файлов, список которых получаю по ссылке в json формате.
При загрузке приложения, я получаю callback, откуда составляю список загружаемых файлов и передаю в другой класс. Проблема заключается в том, что не все файлы скачиваются, отловить не получается, не знаю, в чем проблема.

В этом классе, в методе updateGameClient, я получаю массив и отправляю его в Browser.Load()

```
public class CallbackObjectSaveSettings
        {
            private MainWindow _mainWindow;

            public CallbackObjectSaveSettings(MainWindow mainWindow)
            {
                _mainWindow = mainWindow;
            }

            public async void updateGameClient()
            {
                UpdateSet upd = UpdateSet.FromJson(_web.DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1/update/1"));
                var updList = upd.Update;
                for (int i = 0; i < updList.Length; i++)
                {
                     _mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _mainWindow.Browser.Load(updList[i].fileName));
                }
            }


        }
```

Тут пытаюсь обработать..  ПрогрессБар реагирует на каждый файл по отдельности, и скачиваются максимум 2 файла

```
class MyDownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
        {
            private ProgressBar _bar;


            public MyDownloadHandler(ProgressBar bar)
            {
                _bar = bar;
            }

            public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
            {
                if (!callback.IsDisposed)
                {
                    using (callback)
                    {
                        var downFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "upd\\", downloadItem.SuggestedFileName);
                        callback.Continue(downFolder, false);
                        Console.WriteLine("browser " + browser + ", downloadItem: " + downloadItem.Id + " suggestedName: " + downFolder);

                    }
                }
            }

            public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
            {

                _bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download {0}/{1} bytes", downloadItem.ReceivedBytes, downloadItem.TotalBytes);
                    _bar.Maximum = downloadItem.TotalBytes;
                    _bar.Value = downloadItem.ReceivedBytes;
                }));
            }

        }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина? Спасибо!

Comment: Я не уверен, что вам надо писать так ```mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _mainWindow.Browser.Load(updList[i].fileName));```, замените на ```_mainWindow.Browser.Load(updList[i].fileName);```

Comment: @tym32167 я уже пробовала так, к сожалению, не помогает ((

Comment: Я и не рассчитывал, что поможет. Просто вы грузите файлы в UI потоке, что делать не стоит. А в чем у вас проблема я не знаю :)

Comment: @tym32167 сама не понимаю, расставила брейкпоинтов, и все равно понять не могу, почему так... скачиваются или первый и пятый файлы или только пятый

Comment: А что с json`ом? Все файлы описаны? Пути в Path.Combine соответствуют реальным?

Comment: @MikhailEfremov да,в json'е ошибок нет, все файлы скачиваются по прямой ссылке....  Вот пример:   {  
         "folderName":"Data",
         "fileName":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/public\/updates\/patch-1.mpq",
         "fileHash":"3D4DA9A5AB3E967717F9630165A65CD4",
         "fileLenth":"22975058"
      }

Comment: Что за тип у контрола ```_mainWindow.Browser``` ?

Comment: @tym32167 CefSharp Browser

Comment: оберните ваш код для скачивания файла в try-catch, установите фиддлер, убедитесь, что запрашивается 5 файлов и все 5 отправляются с сервера

Answer (score 0):

Переписала метод, создала очередь скачивания файла. Спасибо за помощь!